Mass Transit State Machine Faulted Handler not triggered
I'm working with MassTransit and I'm configuring my State Machine. The Saga pipeline seems not to trigger the Faulted handler when an exception happens in the Activity.
To test this and ensure the explanation is easier I've tried to use the mass transit sample library (https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Library) and I'm seeing the same thing.
I've changed the NotifyMemberActivity so now it looks like this:
public class NotifyMemberActivity :
        IStateMachineActivity<CheckOut>
    {
        readonly IMemberRegistry _memberRegistry;

        public NotifyMemberActivity(IMemberRegistry memberRegistry)
        {
            _memberRegistry = memberRegistry;
        }

        public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
        {
            context.CreateScope("notifyMember");
        }

        public void Accept(StateMachineVisitor visitor)
        {
            visitor.Visit(this);
        }

        public async Task Execute(BehaviorContext<CheckOut> context, IBehavior<CheckOut> next)
        {
            await Execute(context);
            throw new NotImplementedException();

            await next.Execute(context);
        }

        public async Task Execute<T>(BehaviorContext<CheckOut, T> context, IBehavior<CheckOut, T> next)
            where T : class
        {
            await Execute(context);
            throw new NotImplementedException();

            await next.Execute(context);
        }

        public Task Faulted<TException>(BehaviorExceptionContext<CheckOut, TException> context, IBehavior<CheckOut> next)
            where TException : Exception
        {
            return next.Faulted(context);
        }

        public Task Faulted<T, TException>(BehaviorExceptionContext<CheckOut, T, TException> context, IBehavior<CheckOut, T> next)
            where TException : Exception
            where T : class
        {
            return next.Faulted(context);
        }

        async Task Execute(BehaviorContext<CheckOut> context)
        {
            var isValid = await _memberRegistry.IsMemberValid(context.Saga.MemberId);
            if (!isValid)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid memberId");

            throw new NotImplementedException();

            var consumeContext = context.GetPayload<ConsumeContext>();

            await consumeContext.Publish<NotifyMemberDueDate>(new
            {
                context.Saga.MemberId,
                context.Saga.DueDate
            });
        }
    }

As you can see there are Not Implemented Exceptions being thrown.
I was expecting that if an exception happen in the notify member activity that the Faulted method will be triggered. Inside of this faulted event I wanted to run any actions that need to happen to compensate for the failure that happens, but it doesn't seem to work at all.
Is there something I'm misconfiguring or am I missing some understanding how State Machine failures should be handled?

Your expectation is not the way it works. Faulted is only called on the activity after the activity that threw the exception. It's a railway programming model, and one would almost never implement both Execute and Faulted in the same activity.

Ok, seems like I misunderstood.
You say that implementing both execute and faulted would almost never happen. Why would doing something like this be wrong?
                    When(SomeEvent)
                        .Activity(x => x.OfType<FailureActivity>())
                        .TransitionTo(Active)
                        .Catch<Exception>(c => c
                            .Activity(x => x.OfType<FailureActivity>())
                            .Finalize())

We have an activity that:

Knows what it needs to do
Knows how to handle it's own failure


If your activity handles it's own failure, that's when regular exception handling in the Execute method would be sufficient.

What I'm missing in the regular exception handling in the Execute method is that I hoped that I will be able to use saga retries and run the Faulted handler only when all of the retries have failed.
I can see now that even when a Catch is configured in the StateMachine the retries are no longer triggered as the Catch is transitioning the saga to the next state.

Without understanding the why, i can't really say. Using Catch in a state machine is a very rare occurrence, it's not commonly used by anyone.
